# Specific type is incompatible with an interface [key: string]: any in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I don't know why `MyParams` is incompatible with `Params` in the `cloudFunctions` array. TS says: "Property 'blabla' is missing in type 'Params' but required in type 'MyParams'."

```
// Basic declarations

interface Params {
  [key: string]: any
}

interface RequestFunction<T extends Params = Params> {
  params: T
}

// My function

type MyParams = {
  blabla: string
}

const myFunction = async (request: RequestFunction<MyParams>) => { }

// Export everything

const cloudFunctions: [string, (request: RequestFunction) => any][] = [
  ['my-function', myFunction],
]
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=23&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/PTAECEEMGcEsGNQBMCm8A2kBOkAusB7AO2gFgAoC2I3FLAM0nhVAAVtIBbaUAbwtCgA2gGsUATwBcoaLizUA5gF1pkIuIoBfClRp1GzUACUUARwCuKWQDFzRePmIAeACqgUAD1pEkPdjm5QAF42Dm4APj4BUAAHMOhpFy0dchBQAFlxUHo7B0IiFNxxGJZM-y4eEP5yQQAjTHrIaVl5IgVkynJ4YllQTnFbe0ciYNAYcXtQAAosM0tZaRMLK1xBvOcy%20PCASmDI3lBtTrSAUQ8YgixcdwA3OnFcAAtFFO6Sa4wCcyQ14YThFqKAA001mywWxjmK1%20%20V2QUianESiESlGQmiQgA5P0ALQ5Ib5TEg-ow4hKIEUJRAA)

Answer (score 0):

exactly.

`request: RequestFunction` doesn't guarantee `blabla`, when `myFunction` requires it, because `blabla` is optional in `Params`.

You can make it optional in your type too, if it fits.

```js
type MyParams = {
  blabla?: string
}
```

If `blabla` is required, then you need to specify that in the `cloudFunctions` signature too adding `any` or all types.

```js
const cloudFunctions: Array<[string, (request: RequestFunction<any>) => any]> = [
  ['my-function', myFunction],
]
```

---

The source of issue is `string, (request: RequestFunction) => any`. It means the second argument can be used without `blabla`.

```js
cloudFunctions[0][1]({ params: {} }); // works.
```

but in case of `myFunction` `blabla` is required and such callback should fail.

```js
cloudFunctions[0][1]({ params: { blabla: 'string' } }); // right usage
```

This issue causes the error.

Comment: I've updated the answer, if it's required - you need to specify it in `request: RequestFunction<HERE>` or use `request: RequestFunction<any>`.